# upload file to eXist-db running on Docker container

Tags: docker, xquery, store, exist-db

I'm using eXist-db over docker container - installing Java over Ubuntu, installing the eXist installation headless jar, and also adding data Volume (Azure file) to store all the physical files and the db data files.

I need to upload automatically files to the eXist-db, after I generate a new file and save it to the volume drive (using C#).

According to the [eXist documentation on uploading files](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/uploading-files) there are several methods to upload files to eXist, but none of them work for me.

1. Dashboard or eXide - not relevant since these are GUI applications.
2. Java Admin Client - not working because have no GUI -> I'm getting this failure: 'No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it...'
3. Over REST or WebDAV via web client (using browser or by code), I can run XQuery for queries, but for storing new files, how?

So, the solution I found is to write an XQuery file, using the `xmldb:store` function.

This query saved the posted file using the specified name and location (in the volume), and the stored file can then be retrieved via REST or WebDAV.

But I feel that there must be a simpler solution...

Can anyone help?

BTW, here is the `xmldb:store` XQuery:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare function local:upload() {
    let $filename := request:get-uploaded-file-name("file")
    let $log-in := xmldb:login("/db", "Admin", "admin")
    let $file := "file:///usr/new_file_location.xml"
    let $record := doc($file)
    let $store := xmldb:store("/db/akn", "new_file_name.xml",  $record)
    return
        <results>
            <message>File {$file} has been stored.</message>
        </results>
};

local:upload()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting eXist as described in the [eXist Docker documentation](https://github.com/eXist-db/documentation/blob/master/src/main/xar-resources/data/docker/docker.xml) - with it listening on port 8080 - you can access all of eXist's standard endpoints:

- http://localhost:8080/exist/webdav/db for WebDAV
- http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db for REST
- http://localhost:8080/exist/xmlrpc/db for XML-RPC
- http://localhost:8080/exist/apps for apps installed in /db/apps.

Of course if you've configured Docker's eXist to listen on a different port, just switch the port.

Thus, to upload files to a Dockerized eXist programmatically, the methods outlined in the documentation article you referenced, [Uploading files](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/uploading-files), should all work: WebDAV, client.sh, Ant, or even curl. For WebDAV, if you haven't configured users and passwords, you'd just connect with the URL http://localhost:8080/exist/webdav/db, username "admin", and a blank password. For Ant, see the [Ant tasks](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/ant-tasks) documentation. For curl, you would perform an HTTP PUT request to the REST interface:

```
curl -s -f -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
     -T <filename> \
     --user <user>:<password> \
     "http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/<collection>/<filename>"
```

Comment: minor gripe: all methods work except for `client.sh` since there is no shell in the native docker containers

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible:

```
echo put /home/files/<FILRPATH>/main.xml | /usr/local/eXist-db/
bin/client.sh -s
```